# Is there a version of Recaptcha.Web targeted at .NET 4.0 or lower?

Tags: asp.net, recaptcha

I have a complex project using .NETFramework,Version=v4.0 which I cannot migrate to .NET 4.5 because that requires VS 2012 or higher which I do not have, I only have VS 2010.

I just want to upgrade my ASP project to reCaptchaV2

I get this error:

The primary reference "Recaptcha.Web" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0".

What can I do to resolve this issue?
Is there a version of Recaptcha.Web targeted at 4.0 or lower that I can use, please!

Comment: You are recommended to upgrade your VS, but even without VS (SharpDevelop for example) you can do .NET Framework 4.x development, instead of binding yourself to the dead .NET Framework 4.0 (yes, only .NET Framework 4.5.2 and above are still supported).

Comment: If it comes down to it, you should hopefully be able to follow the [Google docs/guides](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro) to write it out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Download Recaptcha.Web source code from https://github.com/tanveery/recaptcha-net/blob/master/README.md ; compile the .NET 4.0 version they have there using your VS 2010 targeted to .NET 4.0 ; grab the Release DLL you just created and put it where it can be accessed by your projects ; in VS keep your project target at .NET 4.0